# Getting time from network - no response from TimeInfo?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the current time from the network so that my application can show the time in a text view. However, the time only sometimes gets returned to me and I can't figure out why.

I'm using an AsyncTask in order to contact time-a.nist.gov on a separate thread, and subsequently update my text view with a result. This works the first time my application starts, and sometimes the second, but after that I notice that I keep getting stuck at the line:

> TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);

I don't get an exception, none of the following Log statements go through, nothing. It just hangs and my text view is blank. Here's my code:

```
public static final String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rtc_test);

    networkTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_network_time);

    new GetTimeFromNetwork().execute();

}

public class GetTimeFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<Date, Void, Date> {

    @Override
    protected Date doInBackground(Date... params) {

        Log.i("RTCTestActivity", "Getting time...");
        try {
            NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();

            Log.i("RTCTestActivity", "Getting inet address..");
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);

            Log.i("RTCTestActivity", "Getting time info..");
            TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);

            Log.i("RTCTestActivity", "Got time info");

            long networkTimeLong = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();

            Date networkTimeDate = new Date(networkTimeLong);
            Log.i("time", "Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + networkTimeDate);

            return networkTimeDate;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Date result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result == null) {

            Toast.makeText(RTCTestActivity.this, "Not connected to internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        String networkTimeString = "Network time: " + timeFormat.format(result);
        Log.v("RTCTestActivity", "Network time formatted: " + networkTimeString);

        networkTimeTextView.setText(networkTimeString);

    }
}
```

Once again, it will fetch the network time once or twice (or sometimes not at all), and every time after it'll just stay at that above line, as in not print out "Got time info" or even an exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It appears that my connection was timing out, and then my program didn't know what to do with it. I solved this by adding a DefaultTimeout to my `NTPUDPClient` and then putting my connection request in a loop. I try to reconnect every second if it timed out.

The fix is in doInBackground().

```
/** Async task to get time from the network. */
private class GetTimeFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Inform user that we are connecting to the network.
        // Only do this on create, or else it will look strange to the user.
        if (!broadcastingNetworkTime) setNetworkTime("Connecting...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.i("RTCTestActivity", "Connecting to network...");

        // Client for getting time from network.
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        timeClient.setDefaultTimeout(1000);

        // Connect to network. Try again on timeout (max 6).
        for (int retries = 7; retries >= 0; retries--) {

            try {

                // Try connecting to network to get time. May timeout.
                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
                TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
                long networkTimeLong = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();

                // Convert long to Date, and Date to String. Log results.
                Date networkTimeDate = new Date(networkTimeLong);
                String networkTimeString = networkTimeFormat.format(networkTimeDate);
                Log.i("Time", "Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + networkTimeDate);

                // Return resulting time as a String.
                return networkTimeString;

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // Max of 6 retries.
                Log.i("RTCTestActivity", "Unable to connect. Retries left: " + (retries-1));
            }
        }

        // Unable to connect to network.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result == null) {

            // Not found. Disconnected from internet or too many timeouts.
            Toast.makeText(RTCTestActivity.this, "Unable to get network time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setNetworkTime("Unavailable");
            return;
        }

        // Display resulting time in text view.
        setNetworkTime(result);

    }

} // end async task
```

I also changed my return type to String at some point but that shouldn't make too much of a difference. This solution works consistently for me, and I haven't had any more problems.